# Publish KnowledgeArticle via the Web API

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

What is the process to **Publish** a KnowledgeArticle via the Dynamics CRM Web API? I have been able to successfully post a KnowledgeArticle in **Draft** state, but need to move it to **Published** state. Here is my code to publish in **Draft** state in C#.

```
        JObject jObject = new JObject();

        jObject["content"] = kba.Content;
        jObject["title"] = kba.Title;
        jObject["createdon"] = DateTime.Now;
        jObject["modifiedon"] = DateTime.Now;
        jObject["knowledgearticleviews_date"] = DateTime.Now;
        jObject["rating_date"] = DateTime.Now;
        jObject["knowledgearticleid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        jObject["description"] = kba.Description;

        var client = new RestClient(Settings.DynamicsApiUrl + "/knowledgearticles");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("authorization", string.Format("Bearer " + _authToken), ParameterType.HttpHeader);
        request.AddParameter("application/json", jObject.ToString(), ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddBody(jObject.ToString());

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessful)
            throw new Exception(response.Content);
```

Is it a change to a property on the KnowledgeArticle or a separate Web Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to issue an [update request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/work-knowledge-articles#knowledge-article-lifecycle-change-the-state-of-a-knowledge-article) to change the knowledge base article state.

> To change the state of the article, use the Update message on the
>   knowledge article record to update the KnowledgeArticle.StateCode
>   attribute.
>
> ```
> // Retrieve the knowledge article record  
> KnowledgeArticle myKnowledgeArticle = (KnowledgeArticle)_serviceProxy.Retrieve(  
>         KnowledgeArticle.EntityLogicalName, knowledgeArticleId, new ColumnSet("statecode"));  
>
> // Update the knowledge article record  
> myKnowledgeArticle.StateCode = KnowledgeArticleState.Published;  
> UpdateRequest updateKnowledgeArticle = new UpdateRequest  
> {  
>     Target = myKnowledgeArticle  
> };  
> _serviceProxy.Execute(updateKnowledgeArticle);
> ```

The example above is using the SDK Early Bound types, but if you want to use web api, I think it will look at bit like this:

`jObject["statecode"] = 3; //3 = published`

You will probably need to issue that in a seperate update call after the initial create.